# chart.js.... How to delete the number over the bar?

Tags: chart.js

I am new using chart.js.

I have this image:

[image]

I am trying to delete the number over the bar, how can I do it? I am using Angular 9 and typescript but I need to show it only when you click on the bar.

thx

Answer (score 1):

The solution for mi is that:

```
plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        ...
        formatter: function(value, context) {
            return "";
        }
      }
    }
```